# Application is going to hang state, Connection pool issue

Tags: java, mysql

I am using spring dbcp basic datasource connection pool. I have upgraded my mysql version from 5.6.11 community to 5.6.39 enterprise recently. post that I am facing issue like application hang out and my all threads are going into waiting state and It will work fine post wildlfy restart only. If I didn't restart my wildlfy for like four days, Application doesn't work. I took thread dump for that process as per below. Please help.

```
Attach Listener" #35402 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff884010800 nid=0x95d8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"default task-768" #1382 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff63c025800 nid=0xa930 waiting on condition [0x00007ff2e14d7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000005c08c7fc8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"default task-767" #1381 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff3dc00e800 nid=0xa92f waiting on condition [0x00007ff2e15d8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000005c08c7fc8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:

Parameters:

<property name="initialSize" value="5" /> 
       <property name="minIdle" value="5" />  
      <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="5000" /> 
       <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000"/> 
       <property name="maxIdle" value="10" /> -->
    <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
```

Comment: That thread dump only shows 2 threads in the pool waiting for a task to execute. They're not hung, they just have nothing to do.

Comment: Please find another thread dump .                                             
  Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

"default task-254" #509 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe5b0002000 nid=0x7dce waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fe30c3bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:290)
 - waiting to lock <0x00000005c3da15e8> (a org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory)
 at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:771)

Comment: That tells me you have a connection leak.

Comment: But hibernate Template automatically closed the connections right?             class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
  this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);

Comment: Don't paste code in the comments, don't you see what it looks like? Edit the question if you have additional information.